# Evaluate polynomial expression string

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Create a function which takes a polynomial equation, a value for `x` and returns the result of the operation.

Example: given `4x^2+2x-5` and `x=3` output `37`. This is the result of `4(3)^2+2(3)-5`

- Assume all polynomials are valid
- Polynomial format will always be `coefficient(variable)^exponent => 4x^2` except :

  - When exponent is `1` it will be `coefficient(variable) => 4x`
  - When coefficient is `1` it will be `(variable)^exponent => x^2`
- Polynomials are one variable only
- Use of external libraries are forbidden
- The coefficient and variable input can be positive and negative numbers.

Test cases

- `("3x^3-5x^2+2x-10", 5)          => 250`
- `("10x^4-5x^3-10x^2+3x+50", 3)   => 644`
- `("10x+20", 10)                  => 120`
- `("-20x^2+20x-50", -8)           => -1490`
- `("9", 5)                        => 9`
- `("8x^2+5", 0)                   => 5`

---

**Update**

- Polynomial format will always be `coefficient(variable)^exponent => 4x^2` except :

  - When exponent is `1` it will be `coefficient(variable) => 4x`
  - When coefficient is `1` it will be `(variable)^exponent => x^2`
- Removed the rule of negative exponent. My mistake. A valid polynomial does not contain negative exponent
- An exponent of `0` would be just `coefficient`
- Added test case for `input 0`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: How flexible is the input format? Instead of `3x^3-5x^2+2x-10` can we input `3*x^3-5*x^2+2*x-10`? Or `[3 -5 2 -10]. [3 2 1 0]`?

Comment: Can the exponent input sign be `**` instead of `^`?

Comment: @sergiol no....

Comment: Can we take `X` in uppercase?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes...

Comment: What is an "external library" and how is it fair, compared to languages who have "eval" already implemented as a feature?

Comment: My apologies I haven't use my pc since yesterday. I have updated the challenge with the suggestions you gave me. Please take a look at it and reopen it if everything is ok.

Comment: [Please merge the "Update" part.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Comment: (also don't worry too much about slow update, closed challenges can be reopened, etc.)

Comment: Your specs don't match your examples.  It should be 10x^0 under your specs, but your examples use 10.

Comment: Your test cases don't have any coefficients of `1`

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES7), 48 bytes

*Based upon a suggestion from @RickHitchcock*

Expects `X` in uppercase. Takes input in currying syntax `(p)(X)`.

```javascript
p=>X=>eval(p.replace(/[X^]/g,c=>c<{}?'*X':'**'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5BCsIwEAXQvacQN00ap00mjajYeo0BMVBiFKXYouJGPHtNRFDULIZZzPs/h/pan91p313g2G58vy37rqyorPy1bliXnXzX1M6zfEV2ne/Grqzc4nZfJikl8yRNE8571x7PbeOzpt2xLRtpshoMWRRIoOSIM8P58PXyfIhGDr6IkmSLaDTEFYUmYaLUQQYyKYo/RGA8UfKd/tGi8KcF8JkdJjzDYfohAwFVzH6/RhZQhLIo8KsqIJmh6R8)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 49 bytes

Same approach as [@DeadPossum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166110/58563). Takes input in currying syntax `(p)(x)`.

```javascript
p=>x=>eval(p.split`x`.join`*x`.split`^`.join`**`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7RCoMgFAbg@z1F7CqTY3rMsV3Uo0jRahSRsSJ8@6ZtY1HzQg4Hv/@3LeZiLJ/NMEFv7tVSp8uQZjbNqrnowoGNQ9dMuc1Za5o@j9zw3ujvJsrJUpp@NF3FOvMI6/AsrZagrEaKFgQ/k1AREnxOHAeo@GlHBLc68UaCH5FKS5WX0klHLknyh1D0TwT/pW9aBB5aANdsd8MaDteNdAREcjt@zWpA6sq8wF2VQ5yhWl4)

Comment: I think you can save a couple bytes by using `replace`:  `p=>x=>eval(p.replace(/[x^]/g,a=>a>f?'*x':'**'))`

Comment: @RickHitchcock I can't use a reference to `f` unless it's included in the byte count, at the cost of the 2 bytes that are supposed to be saved. I like this method, though. There might be a way to save a byte or two by revamping it somehow.

Comment: Oh, of course.  Hmm.

Comment: @RickHitchcock If we can take `X` in uppercase, then we can do `a<{}?'*X':'**'`, saving a byte. Hence my question to the OP.

Comment: cant handle `x` alone

Comment: @l4m2 The challenge rules were updated. :/ It used to be `1x` for `x`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Jo King

-5 bytes thanks to Arnauld

```python
lambda p,x:eval(p.replace('^','**').replace('x','*x'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvRCgIhEEXf@wrZF3V1QseECPqTEKyEAttkWWL6elv3obaXYTjnnvKebs8Baz6eao6P8zWyoumQXjGLsh1TyfGSBA9c877n8keoEeJS1jLeh4ll0TkKDjwFVEhgTaeZl5uvtYbCrmkH7UXlSPk2cv8jhQ1as6KASzBfWArYrxMKgGrumkFZPw)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>53</strike> <strike>50</strike> 48 bytes

**edit**: -5 bytes thanks to Dennis !

```python
lambda p,x:eval(p.translate({94:"**",120:"*x"}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwFET3nqJklTT9kvw0oAVvIoGILQq1DTXIF/HsNRUptbMYZvF4THjGS9@ZsTkcx9bfTmefhYKq@uFbHrZx8N299bHmr31ZsTxnhUaVBrG3EGMYrl3kDWeGnAFLDiUSaMWK7BcrxGamtCJXTpiBaaI0JO0EmxUlcaGYo9USA/wqUoNd0rD7k5EDlMm4FmK6/wE)

Used `translate` to avoid chaining `replace` calls; Python 3's version of `translate` is less awkward than its predecessor's.

Comment: `"*(%d)"%x` can become `"*(x)"`.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't event figured out `x` was in my `eval` scope ! I'll update.

Comment: Actually, since `x` is no longer a string representation, `"*x"` works as well.

Comment: Even better ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 44 bytes

```r
function(f,x)eval(parse(t=gsub("x","*x",f)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BCoMwEEX3nkLiJtOYkkwSaRf2KIIWFUG0RC3p6VNjpUjpLD4f/uON9UnfVba0L9qMdl6GeoIo2SuVIoOozX2zDPe5GwfapA7qZ9nTR2mnms55Oy0VJY6k5LRGAwC@pUS5QnHjCmTouBQkjQ3E30vyW4xGRCsohSt0IBUPFZlyzARewQ5mWu8gwzBIcTAdjVJuRo6bZ02@ifgFfkAu9fXz3BUc2SoOHMIfpzij8W8)

Fairly straightforward with R. Replace `nx` with `n*x` and then `eval` the `parse`d string. `x` is used as this is how we name the second argument.

The eval function could even be used more directly with a properly formatted first argument, and other formal arguments (`y`, `z`, etc.) could be easily added:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes (non-competing)

```r
function(f,x)eval(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5RC4MgEAfw9z6F0IuX3dArY3toH2XQRkUwalgN9@mdthisdg96or/7a1x8766mMi/eDGaa@3qEKF5brmQBUVu6Zu5vUzf0vEkt1M/qzhtwLa/tw9TjGC6yxF4y1H4lQYlFJSFlGti34vLMSMvoRynpQb6wDJcDCT9J6KAzWFmR53smKLzxMWxXwSi1iUL6jA8bLvPxCBuEKj9tf@gRkgiBwRD8yZIH0u4N)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>113</s> 108 bytes

```javascript
_=>x=>_.match(/-?(?:[x\d]+|\^?)+/g).reduce((a,b)=>b.split`x`[0]*(~b.indexOf`x`?x**(b.split`^`[1]||1):1)+a,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxNboMwEAXgfY@R1QyOHf8UqYoEHKEHIDgYMCkVhSjQahaoV6c4UjdtNqPRvG/eu/tyU33rrjMfxsavbbKek5SS9Cw@3Fy/wYFnkB1zOjUFW042Q3a4oLj55rP2AG5fYZJWYrr23VxSmcsigu9KdEPj6bXdLhlFEfwCW@aqWBaFR4XM7SWu9ThMY@9FP16ghZ0ha3hMVjNNXMkdQoz49AcpSfY5KMPDqpkhFgdrHlqmQ6bk/5Dr@/s2@f2fvzwoIMs121oC0IjrDw)

Thanks to @Arnauld

---

Since the best JS solution so far by @Arnauld (49 bytes) has already been posted and it uses `eval`, I decided to use Regex and reduce instead of that.

Pretty lengthy compared to his though.

## Explanation :

```javascript
A =>                            // lambda function accepting argument 1 
    x =>                        // argument number 2 (currying syntax used)
        A.match(                // this matches all instance of what comes next 
                                // and converts to array
       /[-]?(?:[x\d]+|\^?)+/g)  // regexp for -ve sign , variable number and ^ sign 
            .reduce((a, b) =>   // reduce the array to single (take 2 params a,b)
                b.split `x`     // split b at instances of `x` 
                        [0]     // and select the first instance 
                * (b.indexOf`x` // multiply that by value of index of x in b 
                    > 0 ?       // if it is greater than 0 then 
                x **            // multiplication will be with x raised to power
               (l = b.split `^` // set variable split b at every `x` 
                   [1]||1       // choose first index otherwise set to one
                )               // this is what x is raised to the power 
                : 1)            // in the case x is not present multiply by 1
                + a,            //  add value of `a` to that value 
        0)                      // in case no reduce is possible set value to 0
```

---

Comment: This currently fails on the last test case (should be 0.25). You can save a few bytes by using `-` instead of `[-]`, `~b.indexOf\`x\` ` instead of `b.indexOf\`x\`>0` and removing `l=` which is not used. (But this doesn't fix the bug.)

Comment: @Arnauld: Thanks. No idea why it does that, will see what the problem

Comment: Well, the problem is that your regex splits `1x^-2` on the `-`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0, 13 bytes

```
OvUd^'*²'x"*V
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=T3ZVZF4nKrIneCIqVg==&input=IjN4XjMtNXheMisyeC0xMCIKNQ==).

### Explanation:

```
OvUd^'*²'x"*V
              U = Implicit first input
              V = Implicit second input

Ov            Eval:
  Ud            In U, replace:
    ^             "^" with:
     '*²            "**"
        'x        "x" with:
          "*V       "*V"
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
ToExpression@#/.x->#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8k37WioCi1uDgzP89BWV@vQtdO2Ujtf0BRZl5JdFq0knFFnLGuaUWckbZRha6hgZKOgmls7H8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„*(I')J'xs:'^„**:.E
```

+3 bytes as bug-fix for negative input `x`.

`.E` (*Run as Batch code*) has been replaced with *Run as Python `eval`* in this [latest commit of *@Adnan*](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/6851a84127450743174065d8d7b78229be40f154), but this version isn't on TIO yet. [*@Mr.Xcoder* tested it on his local (latest version) 05AB1E to verify it's working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S57up.jpg)
[See this version without `.E` to see how it converted the expression string.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcM8LQ1PdU0v9YpiK/U4EFfL6v9/Uy7jijhjXdOKOCNtowpdQwMA)

**Explanation:**

```
„*I')J'xs:    # Replace all "x" with "*(n)" (where `n` is the input-integer)
              #  i.e. 5 and 3x^3-5x^2+2x-10 → 3*(5)^3-5*(5)^2-2*(5)-10
'^„**:        # Replace all "^" with "**"
              #  i.e. 3*(5)^3-5*(5)^2-2*(5)-10 → 3*(5)**3-5*(5)**2-2*(5)-10
.E            # Evaluate as Python-eval
              #  i.e. 3*(5)**3-5*(5)**2-2*(5)-10 → 250
```

---

Alternative **<s>25</s> 28 bytes** program that works on the current version of TIO:

```
„*(I')J'xs:'^„**:“…¢(“s')J.e
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXcvTS72i2Eo97lHDPC0tq0cNcx41LDu0SAPIKFbX9NIDqjHlMq6IM9Y1rYgz0jaq0DU0AAA)

**Explanation:**

```
„*(I')J'xs:'^„**:    # Same as explained above
“…¢(“                # Literal string "print("
     s               # Swap both
      ')             # Literal character ")"
        J            # Join everything together
                     #  i.e. 3*(5)**3-5*(5)**2-2*(5)-10 → print(3*(5)**3-5*(5)**2-2*(5)-10)
.e                   # Run as Python code
                     #  i.e. print(3*(5)**3-5*(5)**2-2*(5)-10) → 250
```

`“…¢(“` is the string `print(`, because:

- `“` and `“` starts and ends the compressed string
- `…¢` is equal to `0426` because it looks at the indices in the [info.txt file](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt), where `…` has index 4, and `¢` has index 26.
- This index `0426` is then used in the [dictionary-file](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/lib/dictionary.py), where line 427 (index 426) is the word it fetches, which is `print` in this case.
- The `(` doesn't have an index in the info.txt file, so it is interpret as is.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

```
Prompt X:expr(Ans
```

Expression is taken as argument and X is entered during runtime. Alternatively 8 bytes without `expr`:

```
Prompt X,u:u
```

Here both arguments are entered at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 143 bytes

I know there are better answers but I wanted to do it without using eval

```javascript
(_,x)=>_.match(/[+-]?(?:[a-z0-9.]+|\^-?)+/gi).reduce((a,b)=>~~(b.split('x')[0])*(b.indexOf('x')>0?Math.pow(x,(l=(b.split('^')[1]))?l:1):1)+a,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3tToMwFIb/exVkf@ixPV0pkugS4AqMF4B06fjYMAhkoDbG7Nax7IcyR0yak@b9eN4X/a777Fh1AzZtXoxlOJItMxBGW/6qh@xA1gnFNCbxJtH4KfCBp/TrWWEMdL2vgB@L/C0rCNFsZ0unE9nxvqurgbjGhUSkcGuVqskL81SetUjEj3o48K79IIaROvxtKNvwUoC43nhgH9VMwJi1Td/WBa/bPXHJyjfKx8AoSaVBT6yYE4ATRo7LnHLZhZs/CE8YdTelfJy@kvqGBlPWn5H@CS0BqZw8T1wSftSrCsoz1F48U/F@1lwwrzeNQkntxBSQ89lLA8Zv)

Comment: Your regex doesn't need `[a-z0-9.]` does it?  The only letter that can appear is `x`.  Any why `.`?  You don't need to handle non-integer coefficients or exponents.

Answer (score 2):

## [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 35 bytes

```
->e;x:Eval@Replace[e;"x";f"*({x})"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvyfVpqXXJKZn6dgqxDzX9cu1brCyrUsMcchKLUgJzE5NTrVWqlCyTpNSUujuqJWUyn2f0BRZl6JA0xbtJJxRZyxrmlFnJG2UYWuoYGStYJpLBe6IkODijgTkCpjXRDTSNu4QtsUpNYYq1ptI5CcoQGmpK4RWDuQ1AXr17XAYkBFnK6RNtAUkAKj2P8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>47</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

Saved a lot of bytes by taking the second input as a string instead of a number.

```matlab
@(x,c)eval(strrep(x,'x',['*(',c,41]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dCsIwDEbvfYpSkHb2hzZtRS8mvodYGGNeCcocI29fu3aImouQkPMd8uinbh7SrdVapzNH2TfD3N35axrH4Zl3hkxe2I4z2Utvr02Tbpw6jE4FjCAAlTVUEhpoQ9baEtKeCASzyag1GP3COrWMIByKUBIuJyq6935FBZRTVn5sv1YLxaqguHJXVaYOX4mKKuuP9QWMCkSWFxL@1BU2GkJ6Aw)

#### Explanation:

Fairly straight forward: Replace `x` by `(c)` , where `c` is the second input, and evaluate. The paretheses are necessary because in Octave `-8^2 == -64`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>150</s> <s>149</s> 148 bytes

```java
n->s->new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JS").eval(s.replace("x","*"+n).replaceAll((s="(\\-?\\d+)")+"\\^"+s,"Math.pow($1,$2)"))
```

<s>Not sure if it's possible to have a currying lambda function that throws an Exception. If it is, 1 byte can be saved changing `(s,n)->` to `n->s->`.</s> -1 byte thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* for showing me how to do this.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZBfa8IwFMXf/RSX4EO6mKCpwkB0KPgycHvo47pCWrParqaliRoZfnYX2/ow2CaE/Lk5v3tOkouDoPnm85IUQmtYi0x99QAyZWT9IRIJC7ieAZYgsKuC8sBs6/KoYWUTWZmsVFMnOPd@UMuOeo1zmRiIcWDqTKWg/6IB3NBGmCxxlgJmcFF0rulcySPkLqRlOqmzyrCgWVYqzZRcCyVSWWOPpbIrLU8vYicxeg6Qx@RBFFizWlaFS4WRRQP0gIjybqVFUWCsZwiHIX0Kww3xkEdQGEaI6AFaC7NlVXnE/dGgz92Vd5m2Sat9XLikXeBDmW1g576ue@bbO4g6/eWt7acEJ23kjpV7wyonN4XCggnseyzGaGwjTrilE@c2/U8@aeS@jXw66ZjR8B7UeoyGNhpfKZ9et5z4lkzusqPhDSb8rpg@NmLKm/5upvcNeNvfRpQTZ3LTn3vnyzc)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->s->     // Method with integer and String parameters and Object return-type
  new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JS")
            //  Use a JavaScript engine
   .eval(s  //  And eval the input
      .replace("x","*"+n)
            //   After all 'x' has been replaced with '*n'
            //   (where `n` is the input-integer)
      .replaceAll((s="(\\-?\\d+)")+"\\^"+s,"Math.pow($1,$2)"))
            //   And all `A^B` have have been replaced with `Math.pow(A,B)`
            //   (where both `A` and `B` are integers)
```

Unfortunately the JavaScript eval doesn't support `**`, so I have to use a longer replace to convert it to `Math.pow` instead..

Comment: JavaScript does support `**` (ES7+), why does this not support that ?

Comment: Also is there no eval in java. That can't be right ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Nope, Java has no `eval`. And I think this builtin JavaScript-eval I can use with `ScriptEngineManager` hasn't been updated in the Java JDK for years, so it doesn't support `ES7+`..

Comment: Man, java sucks, no eval why ? Okay why hasn't it been updated ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I dunno.. You'll have to ask the creators of Java that question. ;)

Comment: Good idea, will go ask them (most of of your byte count is for importing the engine

Comment: Yes, [there's an eval in java, since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html).

Comment: And [here's your curried version](https://tio.run/##hZBfa8IwFMXf/RSX4EO6mKCpwkB0KPgycHvo47pCWrParqaliRoZfnYX2/ow2CaE/Lk5v3tOkouDoPnm85IUQmtYi0x99QAyZWT9IRIJC7ieAZYgsKuC8sBs6/KoYWUTWZmsVFMnOPd@UMuOeo1zmRiIcWDqTKWg/6IB3NBGmCxxlgJmcFF0rulcySPkLqRlOqmzyrCgWVYqzZRcCyVSWWOPpbIrLU8vYicxeg6Qx@RBFFizWlaFS4WRRQP0gIjybqVFUWCsZwiHIX0Kww3xkEdQGEaI6AFaC7NlVXnE/dGgz92Vd5m2Sat9XLikXeBDmW1g576ue@bbO4g6/eWt7acEJ23kjpV7wyonN4XCggnseyzGaGwjTrilE@c2/U8@aeS@jXw66ZjR8B7UeoyGNhpfKZ9et5z4lkzusqPhDSb8rpg@NmLKm/5upvcNeNvfRpQTZ3LTn3vnyzc) (148 bytes) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```ruby
->p,x{eval p.gsub('^','**').gsub'x','*x'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBCgIxDEX3nqLMJjptpE0tuNGL6BQcEDddFMdKRDx7nRRE3YT8/96/lvFR0@5YcZ8NP8/3U1J5fZnKuIQIBvoeVi0CS2J41Vxuk0qHznP0GDiSJkZnO6PCsPhAZzluhHqUl7RnHcTxf44m6Zz9lkhNny82H7c/A45Iel4JoKG@AQ)

Saved two bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

---

<s>Since there isn't a Ruby answer yet I added one.</s>  Nvm there was one that used a different approach

## Explanation :

```ruby
->p,x{                    # lambda function that takes two arguments p and x
    eval(                 # eval 
        p.gsub(           # replace all instance of 
            '^' , '**'    # `^` with `**` (use for raised to power of)
        )                 # end gsub
        .gsub(            # start another replace all
            'x' , '*x'    # replace all instances of `x` with `*x`
        )                 # end the replace function
    )                     # end eval function
}                         # end lambda function
```

Comment: [I think using `gsub"x","*x"` saves two bytes.](https://tio.run/##VYtBCgIxDEX3nqLMJjptpE0tuNGL6BQcEDddFMdKRDx7nRRE3YT8/96/lvFR0@5YcZ8NP8/3U1J5fZnKuIQIBvoeVi0CS2J41Vxuk0qHznP0GDiSJkZnO6PCsPhAZzluhHqUl7RnHcTxf44m6Zz9lkhNny82H7c/A45Iel4JoKG@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
ṣ”^j⁾**ṣ”xjØ(j”*;Ʋ}ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGubGZT1q3KelBeFUZB2eoZEFZGhZH9tUe3RS2P///5V0jQwq4oy0gaSuqYHSf10LAA)

Comment: Due to operator precedence, this doesn't work for `("-20x^2+20x-50", -8)`.

Comment: @Dennis Adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 36+2 bytes,  Non-competing

Evaluating a Text field as a formula is not straight forward in Excel.  There is a hidden `=EVALUATE()` function, that can be called by defining a  Name.

In Excel 2007, Formulas > Define Name.  Define a Name called `E`, with Refers to:

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","*"&B1))
```

Then, with Formula input in `A1`, `x` value in `B1`, entering `=E` in `C1` returns expected result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->s,x{eval s.gsub /[x^]/,?x=>"*x",?^=>"**"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvBCsIwEETvfkXIscnaZGPAS9sPKVmwYL14EGNkRfz22C2IehmGeW@uZXrUuavQZ8vP4/1wVnl7ymVS7ciUWjtw1@uGtR1ISqNf9VJuWc2jDkwBIhMaZPBOWxXT5gO9Y9oJDSAVTWATxQl/jkHZvPuOgKu@JKw@7H8OTIBmeQnAVN8)

Comment: Nice approach with hash replacement, but straight two gsubs are even [shorter](https://tio.run/##VYtBCgIxDEX3nqJkpdNG2tSCm9GDyAQccNy4EGslMnj22hZE3YT8/96/pfGZpz7jLhqZT4/jRcX1OaZxuWcDXQerlkCgJIFXvqZ7VNMBvLDHIEyaBJ0Fo8Kw@EBnhTeVeqwvaS86VMf/OZpq5@y3RGp6udh83P4MhJF0WVVAQ34D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 35 bytes

```perl
s/\^/**/g;$q=<>;s/x/*($q)/g;$_=eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZOX0tLP91apdDWxs66WL9CX0tDpVATJBJvm1qWmPP/v2FFnK6RtkGFtgGX0b/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFOQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
(x=#;ToExpression)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@1@jwlbZOiTftaKgKLW4ODM/T1Ptf0BRZl5JtIJCWrRpbLSScUWcsa5pRZyRtlGFrqGBUqyCQux/AA)

Take input by currying: `f[x][expr]`.